# Cant see more than one item in custom menu

Tags: magento-1.9

I just started to use Magento and tried a few tutorials and have been reading documentation but now im stuck at making a custom menu with multiple items.

```
<config>
  <menu>
      <menuitem translate="title" module="test_helloworld">
        <title>Test</title>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <children>
            <item>
                <title>Index</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>helloworld/index</action>
            </item>
           <item>
                <title>Exit</title>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <action>helloworld/Exit</action>
            </item>
        </children>
    </menuitem>
  </menu>
</config>
```

The action is working and its opening desired page, but i have the problem with displaying first item `<title>Index</title>` that is in this code. If i remove Exit then it displays index. What am i doing wrong here do i have to do something in config.xml (didnt put permisions yet) as i am learning so only use admin account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<item>` is the identifier and should be unique. Here you are overwriting the top menu item immediately.

```
<config>
  <menu>
      <menuitem translate="title" module="test_helloworld">
        <title>Test</title>
        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
        <children>
            <item_index>
                <title>Index</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>helloworld/index</action>
            </item_index>
           <item_exit>
                <title>Exit</title>
                <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                <action>helloworld/Exit</action>
            </item_exit>
        </children>
    </menuitem>
  </menu>
</config>
```

Comment: oh i understood it wrong then,still getting used to magento. Thank you for the explanation